# How to view user stories in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Where is the option in TFS to view user stories?

I can see the task but task is a break down of user story!

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened the task, and the task is a child of the user story, then you should be able to access the user story from the "All Links" tab.

Alternatively, select the team project that you want, right click Work Items and select "New Query".  The default query is anything in the project, so change the WI type to User Story, click run and you should get a list of all user stories.